# Image upload in Nuxt.js using axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I've tried almost every answer in relative questions, and couldn't find any solution to my case.

I'm new to Nuxt.JS, and I'm moving my project from Vue/CLI to Nuxt.js, now I'm stuck in sending POST request which contains images and data (FormData).
The **FormData** is appearing empty on the server side (Node.js)

The current **working version** of my code in Vue CLI:

```
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    };

return fetch(`/create`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
```

What I'm trying to achieve in Nuxt.JS **(which is not working properly)** by using nuxt/axios module:

```
methods: {
 async sendRequest(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',this.myFile);
    formData.append('name',this.anyName);
    var res = await this.$axios.$post('/create', formData);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I tried to log the content before making the request like:

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ' - ' + pair[1]);
}
```

And I can see the fields and values clearly as intended.

I've tried adding headers to the request:

```
this.$axios.$post('/create', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
```

But still getting: **{}** in Node.js while printing the request body.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sending a post in Vue and in Nuxt should be exactly the same. If you used `fetch > then`, you can keep using it in Nuxt. If you prefer to use axios, feel free too but don't forget to `async` in the outer scope of `await`.

Comment: Also, try to `console.log` as much as you can to see if the payload if passed properly. And check your network tab in the devtools.

Comment: Sure thing I'm using async/await in all of my requests, the main issue is within the request body. However, I'm only facing this trouble while sending FormData, regular POST request is received fine.
Note: I'm able to log the content of FormData before making the request, and I can see the fields in it, so I guess the issue is only within Axios request

Comment: Where are you using this? Can you show more code please?

Comment: It's inside the methods scope, as the request should be sent on button click.

Comment: Not sure if using `var` is not overlapping at some point with another variable. Do you see your formData into the network tab?

Comment: No, I'm unable to see anything in the network tab, (204 No Content)

Comment: You should at least see what you're sending from the client side. `204` is the error coming from the backend.

Comment: In the network tab when inspecting the request at the bottom you should see what is actually being sent, can you check if your files are even sent? Is it possible your myFile variable isn't actually the file but only the path?

Comment: I have the same problem too. My req.body is empty. 
Did you found a solution?